# Excel DNA Code Access Security

Tags: c#, code-access-security, excel-dna

I have a simple excel DNA add in, created in version 0.32.

In my add-in I am dynamically loading another assembly that is found on a network drive.

When I load my excel DNA add-in into Excel and run my Excel-DNA function, I get the following error :

> {"This method implicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by
>   the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility
>   reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration
>   switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for
>   more information."}

I have created a .config file for the ExcelDNA project in Visual Studio as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DbPath" value="testString"/>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
    <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true"/>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the actual `.config` file that you specify must reside alongside the executable process that is loading your add-in. In this instance, it would be `Excel.exe`, thus the config should be called `Excel.exe.config`, and exist in the Excel directory.

To load a library from a network share whilst using legacy support for Code Access Security in .NET 4.0, you *may* have to create a *trusted* code security group using the `caspol.exe` tool ([click here for .NET 4.5 details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). This is probably dependent on how you deploy and sign the library you're attempting to load. The tool typically resides at the following path:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe`

Using an example command line issued to the tool:

`CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -url file://to/your/network/share/* FullTrust`

It is worth noting, two code access security configurations exist, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit architectures. If you modify code access security using the `CasPol.exe` tool and a 64-bit command prompt, then you are modifying .NET code access security for 64-bit processes! Excel typically runs as a 32-bit process (if you followed [Microsoft's install advice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) so you would need to execute `CasPol.exe` from a 32-bit command prompt, such as:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`